# get user location lat long on cordova without enable their location

Tags: angularjs, cordova, geolocation

I am making mobile (Android, iPhone and WP8) app in cordova with angular. I need to take users lat, long. I used http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/ and HTML 5 geolocation API and angular geolocation Js to get users location. When I turn on Mobiles -> Settins -> Locations -> On I am getting users location, When users turned off their location I couldn't take their location.

Is it possible to get users locations if user turned off their locations at mobile settings.

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/TM71LBh6ttYotOo6t7oX/preview

Comment: Tried this as well, this also not working on mobile app with location off state

Comment: if the location is disabled, the only thing you can try is a webservice that provide a location based on an IP address

Answer (score 0):

No, if the user disables their location you're not allowed to get it. Not only by software, but also in the Terms of Use of the SDKs you're using (Android and iOS stores will ban your apps).

As **jcesarmobile** commented, you can get it with some accuracy the user location based on their IP. For example, it's good enough for getting the user country to set the app language, works like a charm.